# open links in modal view from page layout

Tags: javascript, publishing-page, modal-dialog

I have found how to open any link in modal view thanks to the JS OpenPopUpPage* on publishing pages. 
I would like to use this also with the links I have in my page layout (created by snippets), so that a link is always opened in modal view (in my case I have a "more info" link on every page, but its URL is different depending on the page).
With a normal link I use a snippet of a hyperlink column in the page layout, but if I am using the JS link format I did not success.
I have created a text column with the JS link (with a calculated column)

```
< a href="#" onclick="OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('myDynamicURL',null,width,height,'title ')">My link</a>'
```

But when I try to use it programmatically (in a snippet), it does not work, SP does not interpretate it as a valid link.
Does anybody has a solution or a workaround for it?

**HTML Code Rendered**

```
<a href="#" onclick="OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('myURL',null,800,600,'Topics and discussions')">DISCUSSIONS</a>.....
```

a no working one (coming from a snippet):

```
<div data-name="Page Field: MoreInfoJava">&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(&#39;<a href="MyURL',null,800,700,'More">myURL&#39;,null,800,700,&#39;More</a>&nbsp;info‌​&#39;)&quot;&gt;More info&lt;/a&gt; </div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: Hope now is more clear

Comment: Can you post how the link is rendered in the browser (HTML).

Comment: a working one: <a href="#" onclick="OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('myURL',null,800,600,'Topics and discussions')">DISCUSSIONS</a>.....  a no working one (coming from a snippet): <div data-name="Page Field: MoreInfoJava">&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(&#39;<a href="MyURL',null,800,700,'More">myURL&#39;,null,800,700,&#39;More</a>&nbsp;info&#39;)&quot;&gt;More info&lt;/a&gt;
</div>

Comment: sorry but in comment area I cannot format the text

Comment: It seem the code is getting URL Encoded. Are you creating those links in custom rendering logic?

Comment: I have a normal publishing page with a page layout. The page layout has different area where snippets of columns are set. Among them there are links too. I want one link to open in modal view, so the default would open a new page (or refresh the actual), instead I want to stay on this page and having a popup (modal view) for this link. The only way I found is to open it with a JS, and I would like to set it so that every page opens its link in modal view

Comment: I have tried creating them woth both a workflow and with a calculated column

Comment: The problem is that the code in the snippet adds its html encoding to an already html-formatted part, but if I remove the html tag part - it means creating a string that start from "#" onclick... - SP does not interpretate it as a proper html address

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink column will let you create a hyperlink, but it will block your javascript injection for security reasons (and rightly so - otherwise anyone could write any amount of javascript and have it execute on the page).

There are many ways to do what I think you are trying to do. I recommend using jQuery to rewrite your links after the page loads.